# How does going live with PayPal works?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Our app uses PayPal to make personal payments for a publishing service, we're finished and in way to publish but when we got to the part of changing from Sandbox to going live with PayPal that's where things got complicated for us.

We're totally new to submitting anything to Paypal, I read the guide on [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/#register) and it couldn't be less clear on how to fill the form.

I filled the form to upload the mobile app, but we tripped with several doubts along the way, here I will list them:

- our app is cross platform and we can only choose one platform, do we
  have to submit both Android and iOS for revision separately? Even
  though it's the same app?
- we filled the form but there was nowhere to place an ipa or apk, only
  a field asking for additional files like ad hoc stuff and such, how
  do we submit our build for them to test?

I have to be honest, PayPal guides aren't clear and don't explain deeply many of the processes, as if we have already the knowledge of what to do, we searched the web for guides on how to go live but nothing came across our search.

We developed our app using Titanium Studio and the PayPal supports documents treat every submitted app as if they were natively developed, we are using [a Titanium's module to make all the PayPal work](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paypal), so we have no idea what API calls are made, apparently the module uses Adaptive API calls but we're not sure on this, we only make simple payments, do we still need to submit the app or should we be doing something else?.

As you can see we have zero experience with PayPal and while we wait for a response from PayPal and finish to pass every service we use to Production, we are trying to understand  what to do with this submitting app phase.

We contacted PayPal support asking for a detailed explanation on what to do on our situation but no one has contacted us at all.

Comment: how did you resolve this? We are nearing submission and like you, find it very unclear what the process is involved. Did you have to submit an ipa and/or apk? They note the file limit is 2mb which is far too small for our ipa!

Comment: You just have to fill in the form, the file you can attach doesn't refer to app size, but to files that may function as manuals with visual aids showing the functionality of your app if you feel the limited text area in the form is to small to describe how you will be using PayPal in your app. I contacted PayPal and was told that if they required it, we would had to send the apk/ipa files separately, so don't feel pressure, just fill the form and send it and you'll hear back from them, but do it now, they take some time to respond but it varies, you might be lucky and get a fast response.

Comment: Thank you, Uriel. Approximately how long was the process in your experience?

Comment: well the first response took around 2 days, but after that I got feedback within the day, but from what I've shared with other developers, it varies according to factors like work load and such on PayPal side, usually your form application is handled by one person on their side and that person won't change as far as I know. I just hope you're not short on time, since usually PayPal will make lots of clarifications or worse if you want to use PayPal and aiming iOS, Apple will give you a handful since they want you to use payments with iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the module is using the Adaptive Payments API then you'll need to submit the app for approval to obtain a live App ID for the Classic API's.

Login to your account at http://developer.paypal.com.  Click on Applications and that will take you to a page where you manage all of your apps.

You should see "REST API apps" at the top and "Classic API apps" at the bottom.  Click the link under the Classic section that says "Create and manage Classic API apps."

Then follow the steps from there.